# Are stdin/stderr guaranteed to be closed after process terminates?

Tags: c, posix

I spawn a child process using pipe(), fork(), dup(), execve().

From the parent, is it safe to wait for stdin and stdout of the child to close (i.e. read() return 0 on both), and then do waitpid() to collect the termination status?

Or can it happen that the process will fail without ever closing stdin and stdout? (thus my program never getting to waitpid)

---

To clarify, I'm asking whether the following is safe:

```
while (child_stdin != -1 && child_stdout != -1) {
    poll(...)

    if (got_stdout) {
        n = read(child_stdout);
        if (n >= 0) {
            // do something with output
        } else if (n == 0) {
            child_stdout = -1
        }
    }

    // same for stdin
}

waitpid(child_pid)
```

Or can it happen that child will terminate, but I'll never get 0 on read() or write().

No signals are involved, just poll()-ing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If process `a` spawns process `b`, and process `b` spawns process `c` (so `c` is the grandchild of `a`), `b` can terminate and close its copy of the file descriptor that was its stdout (presumably, `b's` stdout is the write side of a pipe that `a` is watching.)  But `c` still has that pipe open, so `a` will get the SIGCHLD from `b`, but will not get EOF on the pipe.  In other words, yes, it can happen that the child terminates but the parent does not see the pipe close.

Also, it is a common coding error that `a` still has the write side of the pipe open.  In that case, `b` can terminate and close its copy of the write side of the pipe, but the parent never sees the pipe close because the parent is keeping it open.

Comment: The stdin of the parent receives an EOF when it receives a SIGCHLD from a child running in the background, not the foreground. How can I ignore this EOF in the SIGCHLD signal handler?

Comment: EOF is not a signal, so you cannot ignore it.  EOF is not even a thing, other than a convenient linguistic abstraction.  When a process attempts to read from a pipe that no longer has any data and for which all the write ends are closed, `read` and `fread` will return 0.  `fgetc`, `getc`, etc. return an integer value that the C preprocessor identifies by the label 'EOF', and human being shorten the expression "a read was attempted on the pipe when all the write sides are closed and the data was exhausted" with "the pipe reached EOF".  You never "receive EOF".

Answer (score 2):

All file descriptors are closed by the system at process exit. What can happen, is that there is some output stored in buffers, which has not been flushed.

If the child process never terminates, then it can happen, that your parent waits forever and never reaches `waitpid()`.

**Edit:**

When your child terminates, all descriptors are closed and then you will finally get 0 on `read()` (or -1 if something went wrong!). So, you might want to change to:

```
...
if (n > 0) {
    // do something with output
} else if (n <= 0) {
    child_stdout = -1
}
```

Your code won't terminate though, because of:

```
if (n >= 0) {  // n > 0 || n == 0
    // ...
} else if (n == 0) {
    // Never reached!
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. That was just a quick example. Thanks for the answer. I'm picking William's though, as it's a bit more thorough.